# Storyboards: how to segue to different viewControllers conditionally

Tags: ios, uistoryboardsegue

I am using Storyboards for a fairly simple MasterDetail app.  The Master shows a list of services, which are of different types.  Each service-type has its own ViewController.  So depending on the type of service selected, I want to segue to a different ViewController.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create segues from the master view controller to each of the destinations, and give each of them a semantic identifier (in the inspector panel). Then in some kind of IBAction callback for when an item is pressed in the master, you can call [self performSegueWithIdentifier: passing in the appropriate identifier based on what was pressed.

There are several options for getting this callback to occur, and it depends on the nature of your model and the way you want them displayed. Could be buttons, individual gesture recognizers, or one main gesture recognizer which does some hit-testing to determine what was pressed.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  My master view controller has prototype cells with detail disclosure and I was trying to use a push segue.  But the storyboard editor does not allow me to add more than one destination view controller.  What am I missing?

Comment: From any single button, there can only be one segue; but you can create many segues from a single view controller (each with a unique identifier). So rather than using segues directly from buttons (or disclosure controls), use a little bit of code to perform a named segue instead, likely from the tableView:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath: method on your tableview's delegate.